# Criteria Query JPA with pair wise IN clause

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have this following query.
I need a way to write it using JPA criteria Query.

Select a from alpha a where a.id in (select b.id from beta b where (b.tag_key,b.tag_value) in ((:paramkey1, :paramval1),(:paramkey2, :paramval2)) group by b.id having count(*) = :paramListSize)

Note : (paramkey, paramvalue) is a list of paramNodes where each paramNode hold one paramkey and one paramValue. So this tagKey, tagValue pair parameters is a dynamic one.

I have solved the problem with jpql but I see that when I tried to solve it using JPA criteria Query it is not able to create the same query while hitting DB - especially the pair wise part is not configured.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello @saiD, were you able to find a solution to your query ?

Comment: Nope.  it was done using jpql with query param